# How can I do a numerical inverse Laplace transform of a data array?

Tags: python, mpmath

I would like to perform a numerical inverse Laplace transform on an array of data using Python.

I found an algorithm in [mpmath](http://mpmath.org/) called invertlaplace, however it accepts only lambda functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define a lambda that returns an interpolated version of your data.

Something like:

```
from math import floor, ceil
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
interp = lambda x: (1 - x%1)*data[floor(x)] + (x%1)*data[ceil(x)]
```

I am unsure if the linear interpolation will be stable or not for the version of the inverse Laplace you are using, or for your data.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but ivertlaplace doesn't like when interp uses the modulus operator and throws an error: -------TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'mpc' and 'int'  -------- If I try int(x), it throws the error: -----TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'mpc'

Comment: It look like you can replace the built in modulus operator with mpmath.fmod described here: http://mpmath.org/doc/current/general.html